# ARKit - positioning a node in the world relative to world origin

Tags: ios, arkit, scnnode

At the moment, my code loads in a 3D model, creates a node using that model, and displays the node in the scene. Setting the scale/rotation (euler angles) of the node works fine. However, I'm trying to set the position of the node relative to the world origin, and I don't want the node to be attached to a plane.

I've tried setting *node.position* and *node.worldPosition* to no avail; although the position of the node changes, when the camera moves, the node doesn't stay static, but moves about with the camera. I'm new to using ARKit, so I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't figure out what it is that I need to do, so any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:
The weird thing is that if I set the coordinates to say SCNVector3(0, 3, 0) it's fine, but if I go over a certain number of meters away it seems to fail. Is this expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, poor world tracking can be caused by these common issues.

1. **Poor ligthing.**   Causes low number of feature points available for tracking
2. **Lack of texture**  Causes low number of feature points available for tracking
3. **Fast Movement**  Causes blurry images which causes tracking to fail

However, what I believe is happening in your case (which is a little more tricky to debug)... is you are most likely placing the loaded model underneath the detected horizontal plane in the scene.

In other words, you may have positioned the SCNNode using a negative Y coordinate which places the node below the horizontal detected plane and causes the model to drift around as you change the cameraView

try setting the Y position of the node to either 0 or a small positive value like 0.1 metres

```
node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1)  // SceneKit/AR coordinates are in meters

sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

z = -1 places the SCNNode 1 metre in front of your cameraView.

Note: I verified this issue myself using a playground I use for testing purposes.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sadly I don't think it's issue 1, 2 or 3, as I'm using checking the ARTrackingState and it's saying it's normal, and I'm never placing nodes using a negative-Y coordinate.

The weird thing is that if I set the coordinates to say SCNVector3(0, 3, 0) it's fine, but if I go over a certain number of meters away it seems to fail. Is this expected?

Oh, and Merry Christmas if you celebrate it!

Comment: Hi Henry, merry christmas... I'm in Sydney Australia so we had it yestereday!.I've found the tracking to be really good in general. I've built a helicopter simulator app which enables me to fly the helicopter off 2km off into the distance and 1km high until the node is as small as 1 pixel and finally disappears off the screen. In all those tests I have found the tracking to be really impressive.

Comment: The node (helicopter) will even disappear off the screen (smaller than 1 pixel) and will appear again when you start to move back so the node is bigger than 1 pixel.

Comment: Hmm okay maybe I'm doing something weird then with my app. Do you have to attach nodes to a plane, or can you position them relative to the world origin? If you can do the latter, what method would you recommend?

Comment: It’s possible there is other reasons its drifting as you move the cameraView about. Maybe as you look up vertically at the sky...  there is less feature points due to a loss of contrast, and the tracking is not good. But I move the helicopterNode around with  joystick controls & the world position seems really accurate.

Comment: You don’t have to attach nodes to the plane. Some apps I’ve used like Farice/ARShooter - github do not even detect planes.

Comment: My advice to you....  is download farice/ARShooter on github and play around with that simple shooting app. It’s probably a much better example to learn the basics of ARkit...then even the examples provided by Apple. It’s not too complex in its structure and helps with the steep ARkit learning curve. It also uses sceneKit primitive geometry for the nodes... which is better to learn with then loading random dae models initially.

Comment: Thanks Ashley, I'll do that! I think I got some of it to work anyway. Part of the problem was that I was scaling the objects incorrectly I think, and also I was a factor of 100 out on the positioning when I set it (I was setting it in centimetres rather than metres).